# How add text in PowerPoint which on click is replaced by a cursor?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Everybody knows "Click to Add Title" in the first page of the PowerPoint slide - the moment you click on it, the text disappears. This is very useful feature for creating templates. Does anybody know how to mimic this behavior? Is it a standard functionality or requires some VBA code? If so how to get this effect.

Comment: This only works for placeholders. Are you looking change the text "Click to Add Title" to something else for title placeholders and other placeholders or are you wanting this for standard text boxes or...?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are a few different methods to do this. As said, placeholders are one way, and if you go into the Open XML document (rename the ext. of your file to .zip), you can even change the words "Click to Add Title". Another way is to use text boxes and a macro to simulate this.